# How to match nested optional value in rust

Tags: rust

I have this rust code which takes a value from nested optional struct:

```rust
let take_newest = match &self.obj.default_options {
  Some(options) => match &options.task {
    Some(task) => match &task.take_newest {
      Some(take_newest) => take_newest.to_owned(),
      _ => false,
    },
    _ => false,
  },
  _ => false,
};
```

How can I change it so I won't repeat the default value which is `false`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Types are supposed to be meaningful, and what you've done there is only confusing... someone reading `Option<Option<Option<String>>>` will be confused to hell. Better create your own enum(s) representing whatever you're trying to model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, patterns can nest:

```
let take_newest = match &self.obj.default_options {
    Some(Options {
        task: Some(Task {
            take_newewst: Some(take_newest),
            ..
        }),
        ..
    }) => take_newest.to_owned(),
    _ => false,
};
```

(Made-up struct names).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then) on the top level option. Something like this (although you might need an [`.as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) somewhere depending on where things are borrowed).

```rust
let newest = &self.obj.default_options
    .and_then(|d| d.task)
    .and_then(|t| t.take_newest);
match newest {
  Some(newest) => newest.to_owned(),
  _ => false,
};
```

If this is close to the real code rather than a reduced example, `bool` is `Copy` so the match can be removed entirely to give

```rust
let newest = &self.obj.default_options
    .and_then(|d| d.task)
    .and_then(|t| t.take_newest)
    .unwrap_or(false);
```